# Cufon in Facebox

Tags: php, fancybox, z-index, cufon, facebox

Does anyone have pointers for displaying Cufon in Facbox?

I have recently implemented Cufon fonts which work fine, but when it is displayed in a Cufon dialog they arent being displayed on top. I can see that it is substituted though. I know this may have something to do with z-index but wonder exactly on what element/tag? I have tried on nearly all the tags from #facebox to the h1 tag inside the Facebox dialog.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be because the Facebook is loaded in the DOM after you call and apply Cufon.

The (inelegant) solution would be to put a Cufon call in the HTML you're adding to the Facebox.

```
jQuery.facebox(function() { 
    jQuery.get('your-url.html', function(data) {
        jQuery.facebox(data + "<script>Cufon.replace('.selector');</script>")
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I implemented a simliar resolved. I added Cufon.refresh() to the reveal method inside facebox.js. I use Cufon site wide so this fixed it for me.

Comment: That's another way to go about it. Glad you got it sorted!

Answer (score 0):

Cufon should start after loading the Facebox for the content appears

```
$(document).bind('reveal.facebox', function() { Cufon.replace('h3'); })
```